# How To change time in Different time zone like IST to CEST

Tags: javascript, angular

Suppose User select time from Dropdown in **IST (+05:30)** i.e. **13:20** and wants to convert it into CEST timezone using UTC difference **(+02:00)** (In CEST timezone time would be **10:20**), (Means what time would be in CEST timezone)

Answer (score 0):

This could work out. You can change a time into another timezone using `moment.js`. `Asia/Kolkata` is `IST` and `Europe/Brussels` is `CEST`.

For more about `moment.js`: https://momentjs.com/docs.

You need to install `moment-timezone` too. https://momentjs.com/timezone.
This will allow you to use `tz` function.

```
    var m = moment.tz('2020-10-17 13:20', 'Asia/Kolkata')
    console.log(m.tz('Europe/Brussels').format())
```

Here you can find available timezones with its offsets.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones